# Grouping multiple rows in pandas dataframe (text, datetime, and int type data)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (you can ignore the CHARTDATE column -it has been removed):

[image]

Code to produce the above:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(columns=['HADM_ID', 'SUBJECT_ID','ADMITTIME', 'HOSPITAL_EXPIRE_FLAG', 'ADMISSION_TYPE', 'DEATHTIME', 'CATEGORY', 'TEXT', 'ENDCOLLECTION'])

d.HADM_ID = [10, 11, 11, 12, 13]

d.SUBJECT_ID = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

d.ADMITTIME = ['2010-05-08 12:26:00', '2011-10-05 01:03:00', '2011-10-05 01:03:00', '2012-03-08 15:07:00', '2012-06-12 04:01:00']

d.HOSPITAL_EXPIRE_FLAG = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

d.ADMISSION_TYPE = ['EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY']

d.DEATHTIME =  ['NaT', '2011-10-11 12:35:00', '2011-10-11 12:35:00', 'NaT', '2012-06-16 12:10:00']

d.CATEGORY = ['Discharge summary', 'ECG', 'Radiology', 'ECG', 'Respiratory']

d.TEXT = ['text about discharge', 'text about ECG', 'text about Radiology', 'text about ECG', 'text about Respiratory']

d.ENDCOLLECTION = ['2010-05-09 12:26:00', '2011-10-6 01:03:00', '2011-10-06 1:3:0', '2012-03-09 15:07:00', '2012-6-13 04:01:00']

d[['ADMITTIME','DEATHTIME','ENDCOLLECTION']] = d[['ADMITTIME','DEATHTIME', 'ENDCOLLECTION']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I need the rows to be grouped together by HADM_ID, with a resulting dataframe like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to groupby HADM_ID and then upon aggregation you want to get rid of any duplicate results in the resultant rows. I have used set() in the following code. Hopefully this will be helpful to you.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['HADM_ID'] = [10, 11, 11, 12, 13]
df['SUBJECT_ID'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
df['ADMITTIME'] = ['2010-05-08 12:26:00', '2011-10-05 01:03:00', '2011-10-05 01:03:00', '2012-03-08 15:07:00', '2012-06-12 04:01:00']
df['HOSPITAL_EXPIRE_FLAG'] = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
df['ADMISSION_TYPE'] = ['EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY', 'EMERGENCY']
df['DEATHTIME'] =  ['NaT', '2011-10-11 12:35:00', '2011-10-11 12:35:00', 'NaT', '2012-06-16 12:10:00']
df['CATEGORY'] = ['Discharge summary', 'ECG', 'Radiology', 'ECG', 'Respiratory']
df['TEXT'] = ['text about discharge', 'text about ECG', 'text about Radiology', 'text about ECG', 'text about Respiratory']
df['ENDCOLLECTION'] = ['2010-05-09 12:26:00', '2011-10-6 01:03:00', '2011-10-06 1:3:0', '2012-03-09 15:07:00', '2012-6-13 04:01:00']
df[['ADMITTIME','DEATHTIME','ENDCOLLECTION']] = df[['ADMITTIME','DEATHTIME', 'ENDCOLLECTION']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

result = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df.columns:
    result[col] = df.groupby('HADM_ID')[col].apply(lambda x: set(x))

print("result:",result)
```

Comment: Thanks Asad! This partially works, except that the datatypes are not carrying over to the 'result' dataframe - I'm just getting object type back (instead of datetime, int, etc). When I try to change the datatypes back to the original after creating using the set function, the dataset returns to the original dataframe (that includes the duplicate row).